# Motor oil in automatic transmission

Tags: jeep

I accidentally added synthetic motor oil to my 2006 Jeep Wrangler automatic transmission. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

As was said, get a complete flush done on it. The problem is not so much the seals as it will reek havoc on the clutches and bands, which is far worse than the seals alone. Definitely not a good thing. Get it done as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Jeep somewhere they can do a complete transmission flush. Motor oil can do NASTY things to the seals in an automatic transmission.

Comment: I would suggest towing it to get the work done to limit any possible damage.

Answer (score 0):

A differant/wrong oil in an auto trans will damage seals made with incompatable materials to the oil, so the correct oil must be used. Differant viscosities of oils will effect the engagement and timing of engagement of the clutches and bands as the oils evacuation and filling of their servos will take longer, or, shorter depending on the viscosity of the oil.